# What will be the area of the triangle in this case?

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems, area

The vertices of a triangle ABC are A(1,0) while B and C lie on the parabola ${ y = 2x - x^2}$.
If AB = AC = $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}$ , then it's area in sq. units is.………

I plotted the parabola and it came to be symmetrical along the line $x $$=  1$ with its vertex at $(1,1)$. I tried to solve the question but could not approach it properly. Can someone help?

Comment: ?The question is to find the area?

Comment: Yes area is to be determined

Comment: I hope you won't mind. Please encode the image next time if you have similar question like this. This is for the benefit of all the readers.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to encode the image. It would be helpful if someone make the necessary edit. 
Thanks for you r suggestion.

Comment: You could follow [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and do it yourself.

Comment: Try to edit and eventually you will learn.

Comment: @Resorcinol One thing more, your vertex must be $(1,1)$ and not $(1,-1)$.

Comment: @juniven yes, I wrote it in a hurry. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: find point $B(x,y)$ by solving the system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
y & = 2x-x^2 \\
(x-1)^2 + y^2 & = \frac{7}{9}
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

For a shortcut, note that the first equation can be rewritten as $y=-(x-1)^2+1$, then eliminating the $(x-1)^2$ term between the two equations gives a simple quadratic in $y$.